# Netbeans: Build second JAR in build process

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar

I'm working on a project in Netbeans 8.0. Currently, the build process compiles all of the classes and assembles them into a JAR, as expected. That part works perfectly well and gives me the expected results.

What I'd like to add to the project is the ability to also produce a second JAR meant to be used as a library, containing classes that are useful for making extensions to the primary project. Since all of the classes designated to be in the library are also in the primary JAR, the problem is simplified to essentially building a second JAR that contains a subset of the first one.

The behavior I am trying to achieve is that after editing one or more source files, building the project will build both the primary (executable) JAR, as well as the secondary (library) JAR. I would prefer to avoid using a separate project.

I'm pretty sure that this involves configuring the Ant build process, but I'm having difficulty finding documentation on how to do so. If there is a good tutorial or guide on how the Ant process works and how to configure it, a link would be great! Otherwise, is there a conventional method for configuring this sort of behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans creates Ant buildfiles for your project that contains many targets for initializing, compiling, packaging, etc. Adapting this automatically generated buildfile (which may be importing other buildfiles) in order to generate your library Jar may not be straightforward because you would have to follow the build procedure and take into account Ant properties, target dependencies, etc.

The basic idea is that in your buildfile, there should be a target that creates the normal Jar of your project. You can place the following task inside that target to create the library Jar. Assuming the subset of your Java classes that needs to be packaged as a library is under package `common` in the `bin` directory, the task would go like:

```
<jar destfile="${myProject}/mylib.jar" basedir="${myProject}/bin" includes="common/**"/>
```

Check https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html for how to use `jar`.

You can also do this in a separate build.xml outside of Netbeans' scope but then of course you would have to manually launch this build.xml whenever you want to build the library Jar.